# I need a help to fix gradle project sync failed in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I was not able to sync android project that i imported from outside of android studio. Anyone has a solution to fix bottom issue?

Error:Module 'androidsupportv7appcompat': platform 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19' not found.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.optimusinfo.mclmcgill_test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':androidsupportv7appcompat')
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mKRz.png)

Comment: add you build.gradle file content

Comment: what do i need to add in build.gradle file?

Comment: I meant add it to your question

Comment: edit the post and add it as code-formatted text!

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
check the box for Android API level 19(AKA Android 4.4(KitKat)) and install it 
After its installed either re-run the project or just compile Gradle

Also change your targetSDK to 25

Try File > Invalidate Caches and Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137376/discussion-on-answer-by-adam-gardner-i-need-a-help-to-fix-gradle-project-sync-fa).